# Center Gridview Contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
<p>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="Department189" Width="1170px">
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF"/>
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Department189" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TescoBibleConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="DepartmentSummary189" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </p>
```

How can I center the Gridview contents?

Comment: This is my code

Comment: need more information, where is your columns? describe more about question.

Comment: Use CSS `td { text-align: center; }`